# Java Mousepress() to draw images

Tags: java, swing, paint, mouselistener, jcomponent

I create this to draw a fish when the mouse is pressed at the mouse's x and y coordinate. but i seems then that the drawfish method is not being called. I can't find the reason why is it is not working. I would be me very grateful for any help.

```
  /*FishTank*/
  import java.awt.Graphics;
  import javax.swing.JComponent;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import java.awt.event.*;
  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.awt.*;
  import java.awt.geom.*;
  /*FishTank class-contains a frame and the WinstonCanvas.*/
  public class FishTank{

    public static void main ( String[] args ){
      javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
  public void run(){
          JFrame window = new JFrame();
          window.setTitle("Fish Tank");
          window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          window.setBounds(30, 30, 700, 430);
          window.getContentPane().add(new FishTankCanvas());
          window.setVisible(true);
        }
      });
    }
  }
  /*FishTankCanvas is a component that allows drawing shapes.*/
  class FishTankCanvas extends JComponent {
    static Graphics2D g;
    int x = 11;
    Timer myTimer;
    public FishTankCanvas(){
      myTimer = new Timer (2, new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){
          repaint();
        }
      });
      myTimer.start();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
      g = (Graphics2D)graphics;
      //makes the background white
      Color backgroundColor = new Color(89, 216, 255);//light blue
      g.setColor(backgroundColor);
      g.fillRect(0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());

      //  drawfish (Graphics graphics, int bodyX, int bodyY, int            bodyLength,int bodyHeight, int tailwidth, int eyesize,int tailcolor, int bodycolor)

      // Mouselistener and mouseadapter  
      this.addMouseListener (new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {  
          //call drawfish method
          drawfish(FishTankCanvas.g,e.getX(), e.getY(),118,74,1,((int)            (Math.random()*(4 - 0))));
          repaint();
        }
      });

      // x coordinate plus 1 of fish (animate)
      x= x + 1; 
    }
    // drawfish method
    public void drawfish(Graphics graphics, int bodyX, int bodyY, int       bodyLength,int bodyHeight,int tailcolor, int bodycolor ){

      Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)graphics;
      bodyX +=x;
      //colours
      Color[] colours= new Color[5];
      colours[0] =  new Color(0, 0, 0);//black
      colours[1] = new Color(162, 0, 255);//purple
      colours[2] = Color.red;//red
      colours[3] = new Color(255,255,0);// yellow
      colours[4] = new Color(60,179,113);//green

      //draw fish
      // body
      g.setColor(colours[bodycolor]);
      g.fillOval(bodyX, bodyY, bodyLength, bodyHeight);
      // tail
      g.setColor(colours[tailcolor]);
      int tailWidth = bodyLength/4;
      int tailHeight = bodyHeight/2;
      int[] tailPointx = new int[3];
      int[] tailPointy = new int[3];
      tailPointx[0]=bodyX;
      tailPointy[0]=bodyY+bodyHeight/2;
      tailPointx[1]=bodyX-tailWidth;
      tailPointy[1]=bodyY+bodyHeight/2-tailHeight;
      tailPointx[2]=bodyX-tailWidth;
      tailPointy[2]=bodyY+tailHeight+tailHeight;
      g.fillPolygon(tailPointx, tailPointy, 3);
      // eye
      g.setColor(colours[0]);
      g.fillOval(bodyX+3*bodyLength/4, bodyY+bodyHeight/2-bodyHeight/5,          bodyHeight/5, bodyHeight/5);      
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

> i seems then that the drawfish method is not being called.

Well that is easy enough to verify. All you need to do is add debug code to the method to determine if this is true or not. Then you can tell us if that is the problem instead of guessing.

Other problems:

1. Don't add the MouseListener to the component in a painting method. The listener should be added in the constructor of your class.
2. Don't override paint(). Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method. And don't forget to invoke super.paintComponent(...).
3. Extend JPanel instead of JComponent. Then you can just use the setBackground() method to paint the background.

However, the real problem is that when you click the mouse the fish might get drawn, but then the Timer does a repaint which will clear the panel 2ms later, so you never really see the fish. Get rid of the Timer. There is no need for the Timer to draw a fish.

Assuming you want to paint multiple fish you need to keep track of every place you click and then paint all the fish. The two way of doing this are:

1. Keep an ArrayList of the points where you want to paint the fish and then iterate through this list in your painting method
2. Paint the fish on a BufferedImage when the mouse click happens, and then just paint the image.

See [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for working examples of both of these approaches.